# Proportion Of Pixels In A Matrix Column Within And Outside A Circle

Tags: calculus, matrices, geometry

As I'm not the biggest genious at mathematics, I could use some help with a problem. See the following image of a matrix, with a center-tile (origin) and the circle around this origin with r = 0.5 * matrixwidth:

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbS46.png)

In this image, all the green tiles are considered to be part of the circular region (The center of the tile is less than 0.5 distance away from the circle) and the red tiles are not part of the circle. The yellow tile is the origin.

Lets say the origin has coordinates (0, 0). Is there a formula with which I can calculate for each coordinate (x, o) (yes, y should always be 0) the proportion of green tiles in the column at that x coordinate?

For example, if we take x = 3, we count 4 red tiles and 3 green tiles. The proportion green tiles = 3/7. For x = 2, this is 2 red tiles and 5 green tiles thus the proportion = 5/7.

Can anyone help me set up a formula to calculate this?

I need a formula in the form of f(x) = proportion

Comment: I think Pythagoras theorem can help you. Try and draw a triangle as you slowly move along the circle.

Comment: @mathreadler I am working with pythagoras, but I'm not quite getting there yet. The solution I posted below comes close to solving the issue, but isn't quite right yet.

Comment: @mathreadler I have posted a new answer below. Could you verify if this is an accurate method of calculating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Even Further Even Further Even Further Improved answer (a.k.a 3rd improvement)**

f(abs(x)) = (sqrt(r^2 - x^2) + sqrt(r^2 - (x-0.5)^2)) / (2 * r)

This function works for any scenario where the diameter of the circle is >= 0.5. It gives a very accurate guesstimation of the height at the given x coördinate.

The image with the theory/proof worked out in the grid:
[image]

Comment: It looks reasonable to me, but I have not checked it too thoroughly. Nice picture anyway. You can consider learning mathjax typesetting as it is used here on the site and usually helps getting good responses on questions and answers/